# facing problem in storing email of the user , when user login to Angular Application by Firebase Google Login Authentication

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angularfire2

I am working on ANGULAR Application where I am working on login page.

I am implementing Google Login Authentication in my Application using Firebase. I have Already implemented google Login:

- But I am facing problem in storing User's email ,  which logins through my Application.

I am sharing my code of **component.ts** :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup  , FormControl  , Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { ServicesService } from '../service/services.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';    

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor( public router: Router ,  public restapi: ServicesService  , private afAuth: AngularFireAuth  ) {

      googlelogin() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;
    alert('hello');
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    if (user != null) {
      name = user.displayName;
      email = user.email;
      photoUrl = user.photoURL;
      emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
      uid = user.uid;
      console.log(email);
    }
  }
```

**Component.html**

```
 <button mat-button (click)='googlelogin()' class=""> Sign in With Google </button>
```

Comment: while you are logging the email are you getting it or not?

Comment: @ashishpal I am getting a google login interface , After I login , it redirect to the login page ,

Answer (score 0):

Hi Anurag and welcome to SO. Your code:

```
if (user != null) {
    name = user.displayName;
    email = user.email;
    photoUrl = user.photoURL;
    emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    uid = user.uid;
    console.log(email);
}
```

isn't going to run because it comes after the `return` statement... however, the `.signInWithRedirect()` method returns a promise, so you can slap on a `.then()` and `.catch()` to the end of it.

```
googlelogin() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;
    alert('hello');

    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then( newUser => {
        if (newUser != null) {
            name = newUser.displayName;
            email = newUser.email;
            photoUrl = newUser.photoURL;
            emailVerified = newUser.emailVerified;
            uid = newUser.uid;
            console.log(email);
        }
    }).catch( err => {
        console.log("Error signing in with Google!");
        console.log(err);
    });

}
```

I recommend you check out [this link](https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/angularfire2-version-4-authentication-service/) (*[or this updated one for v5](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/google-user-auth-with-firestore-custom-data/)*) that walks you through setting up 3rd-party authentication. That whole AngularFirebase website is awesome for learning Angular and Firebase stuff.